# Swift UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm writing code for a game I am making and am trying to create a `User Default` so that it saves data after you close the app.

```
let UserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
UserDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "hasStarted")
```

But on the last line it underlines `UserDefaults` and says "expected declaration.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: are you writing `Swift3` or `Swift 2.3` ? if you do Swift3 you need to use `UserDefaults` and not `NSUserDefaults `

Comment: *expected declaration* usually means: **You must not run code outside of a function / method**

Comment: Your code is working in Swift 2.3 . Could you show us rest of it? Maybe there's error somewhere else.

Comment: @vadian Thank you, that worked. I forgot to put that code into the viewDidLoad() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you are using Swift 2, then what you have to do is just putting your code inside a function/method:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "hasStarted")
```

like so, in:

```
func applicationWillTerminate( application: UIApplication) {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "hasStarted")
}
```

or here:

```
func applicationWillResignActive( application: UIApplication) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "hasStarted")
}
```

I've called it there because you said that you want it to save it when the app is closed.

### EXPLANATION:

You called your function outside any function/method's body, which is restricted in swift. You are not allowed to do anything outside methods(just in the body of the class), besides for declaring and initialising variables/constants.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you declaring and intializing the variable? If you are initializing the variable outside any method then it will give you the same error you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try another name for it.

Try this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "hasStarted")
```

Comment: I tried that too but it still has the same issue

Comment: Are there other errors showing up in your code?